# Checking whether a input element value contains a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check whether or not a input element's value(typed by the user into the box) returned from

```
$("#emailInput").css("value")
```

contains a certain string.

I have tried various methods seen on google but none have worked.

The HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div id="emailBorder">
    <label id="emailStyle">Email address:</label>
    <div id="emailInputStyle">
        <input class="form-control" id="emailInput" type="text">
    <span id="emailGlyphicon"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="contentStyle">Content:</label>
    <div id="contentInputStyle">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="contentInput"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="sendStyle" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

The Javascript (My Attempt):

```
$("#emailInput").change(function () {
    if ($("#emailInput").css("value").contains("@") && $("#emailInput").css("value").contains(".")) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: dont forget to mark an answer as accepted to guide future readers of this post

Comment: Thanks! I did but accidentally double-clicked it off, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `css()`, use `val()`. Also, instead of `contains()` use `indexOf()` because `contains()` works on jQuery DOM objects, not strings

```js
$("#emailInput").change(function() {
  if ($("#emailInput").val().indexOf("@") > -1 && $("#emailInput").val().indexOf(".") > -1) {
    console.log('It contains @ and .');
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div id="emailBorder">
    <label id="emailStyle">Email address:</label>
    <div id="emailInputStyle">
      <input class="form-control" id="emailInput" type="text">
      <span id="emailGlyphicon"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="contentStyle">Content:</label>
    <div id="contentInputStyle">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="contentInput"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="sendStyle" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) will get/set the `inline style` of an element. [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will get/set the `value` of an `input` type element

Comment: For me it doesnt work and i get an HTML error when i render the page that "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).contains is not a function"

Comment: @shawna, see my updated answer and let me know if you still need help

Comment: Works perfect thanks! I was wondering why everyone was saying .contains() but intellisense couldn't find it.

Comment: @shawna, contains works for elements and search their texts, but no on strings.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#emailInput").change(function () {
    if ($this.contains("@") && $this.contains(".")) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```